# Getting a computed property from a component

Tags: ember.js, components, computed-properties, ember-components

I currently try to get a computed property from a component.

```
export default Component.extend({
    isValid: computed('currentQuantity', 'maxQuantity', function() { ... }),
});
```

Trying to receive it (controller: isValid=null;) with

```
{{quantity-list isValid=(mut isValid)}}
```

results in overwriting the property and removing the computation.

How can I get the isValid property?

Comment: There is something wrong in Your code. Why You're trying to mutate isValid computed property? Mutating is possible in actions not in passing properties to component.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `mut` helper when passing `isValid` property to your `quantity-list` component. The `mut` helper mutates the value when it changes in your child component. You should pass `isValid` like this:

`{{quantity-list isValid=isValid}}`

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind any property value defined in the component is just a default, and if you pass in a property, it overwrites the default.  So in this case, you passing in a property overwrites the default behavior, which is for isValid to be a computed.

In other words, you need to not pass a value in if you want your component to have isValid be a computed property.